# Replacing image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have a problem with some image change when clicking on a tab.

Problem is with the arrow image, currently its coming with jQuery like this

```
$('.toggle_title').prepend('<img class="tab-open" src="my_url" />');
```

So what I need is that, when the tab is open, image changes itself to "tab-close.png" (flipped arrow). Opened tab has an extra class '.toggle_active' (previous class .toggle_title still stays). I have tried something like this, but its not working, can somebody help?

```
  if($('.toggle_title').hasClass('toggle-active')) {
    $('.toggle_active').prepend('<img class="tab-open" src="my_url" />')
  } 
  else {
    $('.toggle_title').prepend('<img class="tab-open" src="my_url" />')
  }
```

Comment: Should `.hasClass('toggle-active')` be `.hasClass('toggle_active')`?

Comment: No, it was just a typo:) It doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Working with HTML in strings is an anti-pattern. First create an image element:

```
// You should NOT hardcode this value, this must come from WordPress,
// but that's for a different topic. See `wp_localize_script` to learn more
// http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script
var url = 'http://creativeagency.ee/holi/wp-content/themes/bones/library/images/'

var $img = $('<img>', {
  'class': 'tab-open',
  src: url +'tab-open.png'
})
```

Next append the image:

```
$('.toggle_title').prepend($img);
```

Now, since you have a reference to image, you can easily change its `src` attribute when you need:

```
var $title = $('.toggle_title') // chache your elements!

if($title.hasClass('toggle_active')) { // typo!
  $img.attr('src', url +'tab-close.png')
} else {
  $img.attr('src', url +'tab-open.png')
}
```

This should help you out, although it is still probably not the perfect abstraction. You may want to have the possible images in an array, and toggle them a different way:

```
var srcs = ['tab-close.png','tab-open.png']
$img.attr('src', url + srcs[+$title.is('.toggle_active')])
```

The above does the same but a bit terser, by casting the boolean to a number, and using `is` instead of `hasClass`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to change the image. It shows the tab-open one, not the other one.